# Why do we say "assistant" instead of "assister"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Is it just arbitrary?

A Google search gives me the etymology of "assist" but not the reason for the convention. It also notes that "assistor" is the spelling used in legal documents.

Related:

- accountant/accounter
- defendant/defender
- commandant/commander

Looking at the list above, is it when it's an official job? For example, if I help an elderly person cross the road, I am an assister but not an assistant? If I calculate the combined total of my bank accounts, I am the accounter but not an accountant?

Comment: Assister appears to be a much rarer variant than assistant https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assistant%2Cassister%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassistant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassister%3B%2Cc0 - same for accountant, accounter https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accountant%2C+accounter&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccountant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccounter%3B%2Cc0

Comment: English "assistant" was not formed in English from "assist" plus "-ant".  Instead, etymology shows "assistant" is from Medieval Latin "assistent".  The "-ant" or "-ent" ending shows a present participle in Latin.

Comment: This is [derivational morphology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), which is guaranteed to be irregular and unpredictable in how it's used. Whether one uses the _-ant, -ent, -er, -or, -ist,_ or some other variant is totally arbitrary (i.e, it's controlled by the unknown history of the users of the words over the centuries, and not by a set of rules, like inflectional morphology is).

Answer (score 2):

(from the comment)

English "assistant" was not formed in English from "assist" plus "-ant".

Instead, etymology shows "assistant" is from Medieval Latin "assistent". The "-ant" or "-ent" ending shows a present participle in Latin.

Comment: The OP doesn't make this point, but it seems relevant that we have "resistor" (in electric circuits) and "resister" (in draft avoidance situations, among other things), but not "resistant" as a common noun. Is there a clear etymological/historical reason for the overwhelming preference for "resist/resistor [or resister]" on the one hand and "assist/assistant" on the other—or is the explanation, as John Lawler suggests, unidentifiable happenstance?

Comment: It's not a Latin present participle according to this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assisto#Latin

Answer (score 0):

In comment, John Lawler wrote:

> This is [derivational morphology](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Inflection.pdf), which is guaranteed to be irregular and unpredictable in how it's used. Whether one uses the *-ant, -ent, -er, -or, -ist,* or some other variant is totally arbitrary (i.e, it's controlled by the unknown history of the users of the words over the centuries, and not by a set of rules, like inflectional morphology is).